# React onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I'm missing something.  Here's a very simple hello world, the goal is to just fire an alert event onClick.  The event does fire when the page loads, but not when I click the button.  I appreciate the help.   Here's a jsFiddle to make it easier to see: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ihistand/4yuagqz8/3/)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <button onClick={alert("Hello World!")}>
               Click Me
            </button>;
}
React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you're going about this wrong, because ReactJS is just JavaScript I don't think your way of firing this event will work.  Your onClick should fire a function attached to your React element like so.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    myClick: function () {
        alert("Hello World!");
    },
    render: function() {
        return <button onClick={this.myClick}>
                   Click Me
                </button>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris-Hawkes, that works.  I had tried something similar before, but that sent me down the wrong path.  Thanks again

Comment: This React code doesn't seem to work in Codepen in 2018. I changed React.render to ReactDOM.render, but still no button shows up on the page.

Answer (score 19):

Note: this is another way to do it if you want something quick/inline:

```
<button onClick={()=>{ alert('alert'); }}>alert</button>
```

Comment: OnClick would keep alerting whenever I loaded the page. instead of doing onClick={thisFunc()}  just do  onClick={() => thisFunc}

Comment: This also works in reactJS, thanks for this +1.

Answer (score 4):

If the function to be run has parameters, is has to be bound to the function as follows:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function (text) {
      alert(text)
  },

   render: function () {
      return <button onClick = {
          this.handleClick.bind(null, "Hello World")
      } > Click Me < /button>;
  }
});

React.render(<Hello / > , document.getElementById('container'));
```

This makes sense now.  Thanks again @Chris-Hawkes for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see why I had the problem before.  The problem came when I was trying to pass an argument to the function:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    myClick: function (text) {
        alert(text);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <button onClick={this.myClick("Hello world")}>
                   Click Me
                </button>;
    }
});
```

This has the same behavior as the original code.