# Font-Awesome: Can I make icon clickable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a trash can icon in a react-table row, and I want to delete the row when the icon is clicked (my knowledge of HTML/JS is very basic). But when I put an `onClick` handler either in or around the icon, it fires as the page is rendered, and not at all when the icon is clicked.

Here is my current row definition. I've tried `div` and `span`, and I tried using a `button`, but the icon didn't display correctly:

```
{
  width: 50,
  filterable: false,
  Cell: row => (
  <div align="center" onClick={alert("clicked")}>
    <i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React onClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486191/react-onclick-event)

Comment: You should also probably be using a `button` instead of a `div`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React event bindings do not work without an actual function wrapper.

Try it as `onClick={()=>{alert('clicked')}}`

See also: [these docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: Fastest ever answer! But it doesn't work... I get a syntax error: `Adjacent elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.`

Comment: A right bracket was missing. Works great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can make icons clickable.  You could go one of two routes I can think of atm..

You can either surround the icon in an 'a' tag or you could use javascript to grab the element (probably getElementById)  and add a click listener to it, with an easy function attached that executes your hearts desire.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the experience to even understand what you wrote! Can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the brackets.

You can just have the function as `alert('clicked')` or you can define a function inside of your JavaScript and link to it in the onclick of the span.