# Exporting 2 different functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-router, components

```
import React from 'react'

function subValues() {
   let num1, num2, res;
   num1 = Number(document.sub.txtnum1.value)
   num2 = Number(document.sub.txtnum2.value)
   res = num1 - num2;

   document.sub.txtres.value=res

}

function Sub() {
   return (
       <div>
           <form>
               First number:<input type="number" className="txtNum1"></input>
               Second number:<input type="number" className="txtNum2"></input>
               Result: <input className="textres"></input>
               <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="subValues()" ></input>

           </form>
       </div>
   )
}

export {
   Sub,
   subValues
}
```

I am trying to export both of these functions. I am learning how to use React Router right now and trying to create a very basic calculator with a Single Page Application. It does not like it when I try to put the subValues function inside of the Sub function. I have tried different ways to export that was shown in [exporting multiple modules in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039976/exporting-multiple-modules-in-react-js/46040368) this thread, but it did not like it when I tried those ways at all. What is the correct way to get both of these to export and be usable with my App component? Thank you so much.

p.s. I do know that the code that I have written up right here will probably not work and is probably wildly wrong. I just typed all of this up and am trying to get to be able to test my code but can't until I can use both functions

Comment: Share your code how are you accessing these two exports?

Comment: I am just importing it on my App component right now, like import Sub from './Sub'. It doesn't let me export without using "export default" which then I can only export the one function. So I guess I need to put the subValues function inside the Sub function?

Comment: Don't mix JSX and vanilla DOM manipulation, you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React onClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486191/react-onclick-event)

Comment: If the problem is not the `onClick` event, please provide a [mcve], so at least the part where you're trying to import the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You export like this:

```
export const subValues = () => {}
export const Sub= () => (<div> ... </div>);
```

And to import you can do this:

```
import { subValues , Sub } from './youClass.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

A.js

```
export function myFunction() {}
```

B.js

```
import { myFunction } from './A'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can export on different lines and the import like this

```js
// Sub.js

import React from 'react'

export function subValues() {
 // content
}

export function Sub() {
 // content
}


// and where you want to import this, App.js
import { Sub, subValues } form './Sub';
```